# How can I merge two different hard drives for Windows Server?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2008, merge

I have two hard disk drives, each of 1TB size.

How can I merge them and make them one drive in Windows Server 2008?

After doing that, how can I reinstall Windows on those hard drives, keeping the data?

Comment: Do you mean like a mirrior RAID?  Unless they are not at capacity it might not be possible to "merge" them and that certainly isn't the correc term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for RAID0, also known as striping. Check out [this web page](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Windows_Server_2008_Striped_%28RAID_0%29_Volumes) for more information.

As far as keeping data on both drives? You'll need to transfer it off the drives and recopy it over. I HIGHLY recommend [having a backup](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html) and restoring it with that method. Although RAID0 is faster then individual disks, you are DOUBLING your risk for data loss on BOTH drives. Make sure all critical data is [backed up](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html)!!!

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting your spelling, because I don't want to titillate our readers too much. :)